# Navigating UML associations in OCL

Tags: eclipse, uml, ocl, eclipse-mdt

I'm trying to navigate UML associations in OCL, using the eclipse OCL implementation. I know that UML `Associations` are treated as `Attributes`, and the `getAttributes()` function called on a `Class` will return a set containing the `Attributes` as well as a `Property` object for each `Association`. What I need however, is not the `Property`, but the `Class` on the other end of the `Association`.

For bidirectional `Associations`, the following code works, although it doesn't seem very elegant:

`self.getAllAttributes().opposite.class`

Not only is it not elegant, it also doesn't work on directed `Associations` (there is not opposite `Property` there). Is there a better way of navigating `Associations` in OCL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using property.type?

Comment: You're right: using `self.getAllAttributes().type.oclAsType(Class)` works (as long as all the attributes are associations, of course). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try with the OCL console as explained in this post

http://lowcoupling.com/post/47845805110/ocl-and-the-eclipse-ocl-console